# React Redux: Unable to Map array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

how to map returned Array of Objects? When i click the button to fetch the blogs, i am getting this response

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIc5b.png) and [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRvvt.png)

Now in my app js,

```js
import React from 'react';
import Blog from '../components/Blog';
import Form from '../components/Form';
import Root from '../components/Root';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import axios from 'axios';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class App extends React.Component {

render(){

return(
 <Router history={browserHistory}>
 <Route path={'/'} component={Root}>
  <IndexRoute component={ () => (<Blog blog_posts={this.props.posts} fetchBlogs={this.props.fetchBlogs} />) } ></IndexRoute>
  <Route path={'/form'} component={Form}></Route>
 </Route>
 </Router>
);
}
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
 return {
  posts: state.blogs
 };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
return {
 fetchBlogs : () => {
 dispatch(
 { type: "FETCHING_BLOG" },
 axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
 .then( (response) => {
  dispatch({
   type: "FETCHING_SUCCESS",
   payload: response.data
  })
 } )
 .catch( (err) => {
  dispatch({
   type: "FETCHING_ERROR",
   payload: err
  })
 })
 );
 }
};
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

i am passing the `posts` from `mapStateToProps`( which holds the response data)  thru props into Blog Component in the `IndexRoute`.

in my Blog Component, iam logging the passed props (as seen in the image above) and it is passed fine.  Now it is the `blog_posts`.. now i am mapping the `blog_posts` and doesnt work and returns `ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. Please explain why is it not working.. maybe `blog_post` should contain another array which the values shouldbe stored there??? Please kindly explain what im doing wrong

My blog component:

```js
import React from 'react';

class Blog extends React.Component {
render(){
 console.log("Passed", this.props);
 
 let b = this.props.blog_posts.map(item => {
  console.log(item)
 });
 
 return(
 <div>
  <button onClick={() => this.props.fetchBlogs()}>Fetch Users!</button>
 </div>
 );
}
}

export default Blog;
```

reducer:

```js
const initBlogState = {
 fetching: false,
 fetched: true,
 blogs: [],
 error: null
};

export default function blogReducer (state = initBlogState, action) {
 switch(action.type)
 {
  case "FETCHING_BLOG":
   state = {
    ...state,
    fetching: true
   };
   break;
  case "FETCHING_SUCCESS":
   state = {
    ...state,
    fetched: true,
    blogs: action.payload
   };
   break;
  case "FETCHING_ERROR":
   state = {
    ...state,
    fetched: false,
    error: action.payload
   };
   break;
  default:
   break;
 }
 return state;
};
```

Provider:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './container/App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';

ReactDOM.render(
 <Provider store={store}>
  <App />
 </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Store:

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import blogReducer from './reducers/blogReducer';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const store = createStore(
 blogReducer,
 {},
 applyMiddleware(thunk, logger())
);

export default store;
```

Comment: Im sorry, totally off-topic but how can you even read this with such indent style?

Comment: sorry sir will edit it

Comment: Where's your Provider ?

Comment: edited sir. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so Ive solved my problem. the map function is already firing(even the axios request is not done returning the data yet) when i clicked the `fetch user` button in my `Blog` component.. so i have created a function which checks the `fetched` state in my reducer initial state. using thus code

```
if (this.props.fetched === true)
    {
        console.log("passed: ", this.props);
        console.log("blogs: ", this.props.blog_post);

        let b;
        b = this.props.blog_post.blogs.map(item => {
            return console.log(item)
        });

    }
```

then i found out that in my initial state in my reducer, the `fetched` is mistakenly assigned already in `true`! so i changed it in `false`

Answer (score 2):

Regarging the

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

You can try defining default prop types for the Blog component.

```
Blog.defaultProps = {
    blog_posts: []
}
```

But this might not fix it and it might be related to the other error you are doing.

More important thing is that the map function should be used to return a transformed collection of the one on which .map is invoked.
So in your case, you are not returning any object from map, you are using (I am wondering how this code did not report compilation errors because map should return a value):

```
let b = this.props.blog_posts.map(item => {
    console.log(item)
});
```

If you just want to iterate trough the collection, use .forEach insted of .map, and if your intention is to use .map to transform the collection into a new collection, then your function should **return** a value, not just console.log something.
It should look like this:

```
let b = this.props.blog_posts.map(item => {
    console.log(item);
    return item; // you can transform the item here however you like
});
```

Although I think that there is no need to console.log anything inside a .map iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `axios` to send an ajax request, so when you were calling `map` on `blog_posts`, the data weren't returned yet. Use **redux-promise**: https://github.com/acdlite/redux-promise

Comment: arent the data was already returned sir because it is logging in the console?

Comment: In the images, there are 2 log statements. 1 with `undefined` which is before the data is returned, and 1 with the correct data which is the result of running `render()` again after the `props` is changed. I suppose you got the error before rerendering

Comment: so whenever i click the button to fetch the user, it already maps (having the data undefined)?